# problemas com distinct no mysql

Tags: mysql

Galera tenho um select onde tenho que ordenar ele pelo campo 'qtd' o problema é que tenho esse campo diferente, e preciso que os produtos não se repitam.

O campo 'a.id' armazena o código do produto, ou seja não pode repetir.
Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

O campo 'b.qtd' tem que ser a soma das duas tabelas do UNION.

Segue meu select:

```
SELECT 
        DISTINCT a.id, 
        a.unidade, 
        a.posicao, 
        a.nome, 
        a.peso, 
        sum(b.qtd) quant 
    FROM 
        produtos a, 
        produtos_pedidos b 
    WHERE 
        a.id = b.id_produto 
        and b.id_pedido IN (3,2) 
    GROUP BY 
        a.id, 
        a.unidade, 
        a.posicao, 
        a.nome, 
        a.peso 

    UNION

    SELECT 
        DISTINCT c.id, 
        c.unidade, 
        c.posicao, 
        c.nome, 
        c.peso, 
        sum(d.qtd) quant 
    FROM 
        produtos c, 
        pedidos_barganha d 
    WHERE 
        c.id = d.id_produto 
        and d.id_pedido IN (3,2) 
    GROUP BY 
        c.id, 
        c.unidade, 
        c.posicao, 
        c.nome, 
        c.peso
    ORDER BY quant DESC
```

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta. Você que fazer `distinct` só pelo id? É isso? Se sim, você pode fazer `select distinct (a.id), a.unidade, a.posicao....`

Comment: É isso mesmo, os 'a.id' e 'c.id' não podem se repetir, e o 'quant' tem que ser o total das 'qtd'. Tentei da sua forma e continua repetindo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O seu problema é que você possui 2 tabelas com informações distintas e quer somá-las. Sua solução pode funcionar, mas vai demandar um pouco de tempo.

Como solução alternativa posso sugerir o uso de uma tabela temporária, que pode ser muito mais simples de usar, ao mesmo tempo em que mantém o código bem legível.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE resultados (
  id_produto INT NOT NULL,
  qtd INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO resultados(id_produto, qtd)
SELECT
  A.id,
  SUM(B.qtd)
FROM produtos AS A
INNER JOIN produtos_pedidos AS B
  ON (A.id = B.id_produto)
WHERE B.id_pedido IN (3,2) 
GROUP BY A.id;

INSERT INTO resultados(id_produto, qtd)
SELECT
  A.id,
  SUM(B.qtd)
FROM produtos AS A
INNER JOIN pedidos_barganha AS B
  ON (A.id = B.id_produto)
WHERE B.id_pedido IN (3,2) 
GROUP BY A.id;

/* ADICIONA UM INDICE PARA MELHORAR A CONSULTA */
ALTER TABLE resultados ADD KEY `indice_temporario_01` (id_produto);

SELECT
  A.id_produto,
  SUM(A.qtd) AS QUANTIDADE,
  B.unidade, 
  B.posicao, 
  B.nome, 
  B.peso
FROM resultados AS A
INNER JOIN produtos AS B
  ON (A.id_produto = B.id)
GROUP BY A.id_produto
ORDER BY QUANTIDADE;
```

**Observação**: Estou considerando que tanto o produto quando sua quantidade sejam inteiros. Altere a criação da tabela para os tipos de dados corretos caso seja necessário.

Esta consulta irá trazer a quantidade somadas das tabelas de `produtos_pedido` e `pedidos_barganha`.

**Um detalhe importante**: Estou entendo que a coluna `id` da tabela `produtos` é uma chave única. Por este motivo, não há necessidade de colocar as demais colunas na cláusula `GROUP BY`.

**Uma última dica de performance**: Caso seja possível, você ainda pode mudar a criação da tabela temporária para utilizar uma engine mais rápida como o `MYISAM` ao invés do padrão `InnoDb`.

Comment: Bom, a quantidade não vai ser sempre inteira, pois tem produtos que são vendidos em KG. tentei fazer da sua forma, porém estou com esse erro '#1054 - Coluna 'A.id' desconhecida em 'field list''

Comment: Havia um erro no último select. Fiz um pequeno ajuste para pegar corretamente o nome da coluna.
Se puder disponibilizar o CREATE TABLE de suas tabelas seria melhor, pois podemos construir querys mais acertivas.

Comment: ok agora deu certo, e como eu ordeno ele pelo campo quantidade?

Comment: Você pode adicionar um ORDER BY na ultima consulta. Vou editar a resposta e adicionar a ordenação

Comment: muito bom :) obrigado

Answer (score 5):

Fazendo um JOIN entre o `produtos` e uma união dos `produtos_pedidos` deveria satisfazer isso. Algo assim:

```sql
SELECT
  a.id,
  a.unidade,
  a.posicao,
  a.nome,
  a.peso,
  sum(d.qtd) quant
FROM
 produtos a JOIN
(
 SELECT b.id_produto, b.qtd
 FROM produtos_pedidos b
 WHERE b.id_pedido IN (3,2)

 UNION ALL

 SELECT c.id_produto, c.qtd
 FROM pedidos_barganha c 
 WHERE c.id_pedido IN (3,2)
) d ON a.id = d.id_produto
GROUP BY  
  a.id,
  a.unidade,
  a.posicao,
  a.nome,
  a.peso
ORDER BY quant DESC
```

Comment: bom esta dando esse erro '#1054 - Coluna 'b.id_produto' desconhecida em 'field list''

Comment: adicionei o `b` na tabela produtos_pedidos. É um simples alias. =D

Comment: agora deu esse erro aqui '1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column '0aaaaa9006a38a4698ada2dde6bd2a3a.a.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by'

Comment: coloquei o `GROUP BY` que estava faltando.

Comment: deu certo, muito obrigado

Comment: notei um problema, os produtos com as qtd iguais não aparecem e não são somados no sum, tem como arrumar isso?

Comment: Sim, use o `UNION ALL` em vez do `UNION`. editei a resposta.

Comment: OK deu certinho, muito obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Então amigo, tentou fazer com subqueries?
Algo neste sentido:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, 
    a.unidade, 
    a.posicao, 
    a.nome, 
    a.peso, 
    sum(b.qtd) quant
FROM ( 
    (SELECT 
        a.id, 
        a.unidade, 
        a.posicao, 
        a.nome, 
        a.peso, 
        sum(b.qtd) quant 
    FROM 
        produtos a, 
        produtos_pedidos b 
    WHERE 
        a.id = b.id_produto 
        and b.id_pedido IN (3,2) 
    GROUP BY 
        a.id, 
        a.unidade, 
        a.posicao, 
        a.nome, 
        a.peso

    UNION

    SELECT 
        c.id, 
        c.unidade, 
        c.posicao, 
        c.nome, 
        c.peso, 
        sum(d.qtd) quant 
    FROM 
        produtos c, 
        pedidos_barganha d 
    WHERE 
        c.id = d.id_produto 
        and d.id_pedido IN (3,2) 
    GROUP BY 
        c.id, 
        c.unidade, 
        c.posicao, 
        c.nome, 
        c.peso
    ORDER BY quant DESC) as tbl
)
```

Desta forma você aplicaria o DISTINCT nos resultados finais e não em cada tabela individual.

**UPDATE:** Fiz uma alteração no código, veja se funciona, inseri os alias para cada tabela ali em cima

**UPDATE 2:** Nova alteração no código, reduzi para uma tabela virtual apenas. Tente verificar agora

Comment: Entendi, tentei aqui e esta dando esse erro. #1248 - Cada tabela derivada deve ter seu próprio alias

Comment: bom o erro agora e esse aqui '#1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'as tbl2
)' na linha 49'